# Opposite of FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android

I have A fragment which plays videos. On this fragment I wish that the user will bbe able to rotate screen and keep screen always on. I have set the flag FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON but how do I revert it to the default/previous state?

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mainHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTextTask)
    requireActivity().requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    //requireActivity().window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) //revert this
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    requireActivity().requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR
    requireActivity().window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
}
```

Comment: You can use `requireActivity().window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)`

Answer (score 0):

It's described at [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock)

> You don't need to clear the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag unless you no longer want the screen to stay on in your running application

Comment: I wish to keep screen on only in specific fragmnet

Comment: @Dim You need to use activity with `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` or `android:keepScreenOn` flags. For fragment you need to manage visible fragment and clear or add flags